# React native - Set default values for component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a component (Button), which can be modified using some props. It should be possible to change the background color of the button. In case that this color is not set, a default value should be used. How can I achieve this? :)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';

const button = (props) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('');
    const [color, setColor] = React.useState('');
    const [icon, setIcon] = React.useState('');
    const [rounded, setRounded] = React.useState('');
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setColor(props.color != null ? props.color : '#8a4a5s');
        setTitle(props.title);
        setIcon(props.icon);
        setRounded(props.rounded);
        setDisabled(props.disabled);
    }, [props.color, props.title, props.icon, props.rounded]);

    return (
        <Button icon={icon} mode="contained" color={color} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')} disabled={disabled}>
            {title}
        </Button>
    );
};

export default button;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the code provided not working as expected?

Comment: I just found out that the color I picked (8A4A5S), is (yes there is an s inside) of course not valid. Changed that and it works now :) Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Are you using the state in the component other than passing it to the button?

Comment: No, only for the component. Why are you asking? :)

Comment: There's no need for the state here. You can directly pass the props as shown below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default value by destructuring the `props`. Your component can be simplified to this given that the `props` are all for the `Button` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';

const CustomButton = ({ color = "#8a4a5s", title, ...props }) => (
  <Button
    {...props}
    color={color}
    mode="contained"
    onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
  >
    {title}
  </Button>
);

export default CustomButton;
```